# button clicked fire when other function is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is that what would be happened if I push a button and buttons 'onClick' handler fire while other function is still running. Dose JavaScript handle both ( button 'onclick' function and the current running function) simultaneously ?

Comment: No Javascript is always single threaded. Thus your function call will be run from a queue of function one by one.

Comment: thanks for your comment. so you mean that at first the current function will finished and after that my onclick will trigger? am i right?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you include `html`, `javascript` at Question?

Comment: yes. Suppose you have a submit type button having onclick function. Your onclick function will called first then the form will be submitted.

Comment: @guest271314 , I'm trying to understand that what will happen( how dose javascript execute functions ) if there is a function that it is running and user click on a button and it's onclick function fired.

Comment: Ok. Here you have highlighted another scenario. Javascript keeps the function in execution queue pool. After completing current function it would pop next function to execute. In purport, javascript works in a synchronous way

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan, I get the point there. tanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you can't do this EXCEPT another function processing/executing AJAX. because ajax process is working synchronously.